# Find the subject of a specific email - imap -python

Tags: python, imap

I need to find an email whose subject is 'Reset Password' from a particular sender named - xteam and then do some further actions with that mail

If I do this:

```
 imap_host = 'imap.gmail.com'
 imap_user = 'abc@gmail.com'
 imap_pass = 'pass113'

 imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_host)

 imap.login(imap_user, imap_pass)   
 status, message = imap.search(None, '(SUBJECT "Reset Password")')
```

There are many other senders in addition to xteam who have sent emails with 'Reset Password' subject

then I tried:

```
 status, message = imap.search(None, '(FROM "help@xteam.com")')
```

but xteam has sent many other irrelevant emails

Lastly:

```
 status, message = imap.search(None, '(AND (FROM "help@xteam.com") (SUBJECT "Reset Password"))')
```

This gives error:

imaplib.IMAP4.error: SEARCH command error: BAD [b'Could not parse command']

Which is the best possible way to do it.

Comment: AND is the default. There's no keyword for that, it's the default. `status, message = imap.search(None, 'FROM "help@xteam.com" SUBJECT "Reset Password"')` ought to work. If not, [try reading the spec.](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501#section-6.4.4)

Comment: thanks @arnt for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `search` function doesn't decode bracketed strings: it is expecting multiple parameters:

```
status, message = imap.search(None, 'FROM', "help@xteam.com", 'SUBJECT', "Reset Password")
```

`AND` does not need to be specifed because it is the default so brackets are meaningless. The `OR` operator doesn't need brackets either, because it takes only two operands. You can't do `OR tag1 value1 tag2 value2 tag3 value3` because that would mean `OR tag1 value1 tag2 value2 [AND] tag3 value3`. Instead you do `OR OR tag1 value1 tag2 value2 tag3 value3`. Because of the rule about only two operands, that is implicitly bracketed as if it were `OR ( OR tag1 value1 tag2 value2 ) tag3 value3`. This Polish notation makes the IMAP parser easier to write, at the cost of of making complex queries involving `OR` difficult to get right. Below is the complete syntax for what a search key can look like:

```
search      = "SEARCH" [SP "CHARSET" SP astring] 1*(SP search-key)
```

but using `imaplib` you can leave the encoding as `None` to get the default. You can have multiple search-keys of the form

```
search-key  = "ALL" / "ANSWERED" / "BCC" SP astring /
              "BEFORE" SP date / "BODY" SP astring /
              "CC" SP astring / "DELETED" / "FLAGGED" /
              "FROM" SP astring / "KEYWORD" SP flag-keyword /
              "NEW" / "OLD" / "ON" SP date / "RECENT" / "SEEN" /
              "SINCE" SP date / "SUBJECT" SP astring /
              "TEXT" SP astring / "TO" SP astring /
              "UNANSWERED" / "UNDELETED" / "UNFLAGGED" /
              "UNKEYWORD" SP flag-keyword / "UNSEEN" /
              "DRAFT" / "HEADER" SP header-fld-name SP astring /
              "LARGER" SP number / "NOT" SP search-key /
              "OR" SP search-key SP search-key /
              "SENTBEFORE" SP date / "SENTON" SP date /
              "SENTSINCE" SP date / "SMALLER" SP number /
              "UID" SP sequence-set / "UNDRAFT" / sequence-set /
              "(" search-key *(SP search-key) ")"
```

As the last line shows, you *can* include brackets but they must be separate parameters.